# Shortest-path algorithm: multiple source, closest destination

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, path-finding

Algorithms like the Bellman-Ford algorithm and Dijkstra's algorithm exist to find the shortest path from a single starting vertex on a graph to every other vertex. Their multiple source version can be achieved by reversing all the edges and treating destination as start node.

I'd like to extend that to find the "barycentre" of the sources on the graph, *ie* the vertex that is "closest" to a set of sources, finding "fair" paths to a "consensual" vertex.

Are there algorithms already providing this? What are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Floyd–Warshall algorithm](Https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)

I think you want to calculate the "Graph Eccentricity" of **the sources** (S1,S2,...Sn-1,Sn).

1. Use Floyd-Warshall algorithm to calculate All Pair of Shortest Path in graph.
2. Find the result node V in graph, which is the min sum of (d[v,S1]+d[v,S2]+d[v,S3]....d[v,Sn-1]+d[v,Sn])

More Information:

[Graph Eccentricity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphEccentricity.html)

**UPDATE**

Maybe finding an existed node v In Graph G(V,E) which the distance to **S** are  all equal is not realistic. You can calculate the Stand Deviation of (d[v,S1],d[v,S2],d[v,S3]....d[v,Sn-1],d[v,Sn]) between a range that grater or equal than 0 and less than a certain value you choose.

Comment: It will take me a little while to check if it fits my need (and accept the answer). Meanwhile: thanks you! :)

Comment: @AlbanDericbourg "Calculate the min of the sum". I have updated the answer.

Comment: I'll probably have to determine a different metric, but the idea seems good to me (I not only need to find the closest vertex, but also to have fair distances between the destination and every source vertex).

Comment: @AlbanDericbourg From step 2, it's a classical LP problem. You can just update your constants to satisfy your requirement. I will update the answer soon.

Comment: @AlbanDericbourg I have updated the answer. I think Stand Deviation is a good index for you to calculate the "fair" paths

Comment: Tried it tonight: that's what I needed. Thanks!